# How to add a toggle true/false field in cms page general section

Tags: magento2, cms, cms-pages

In Magento 2.4.2, How to add a toggle true/false field in cms page general section along with the default cms page save?

Comment: do you have any custom module in magento2 installation ?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming You have a custom module.

To add new filed in CMS page, first we need to add a new column in `cms_page` table.

create:

> app/code/Pawan/SampleModule/Setup/Patch/Schema/PatchName.php

```
<?php

namespace Pawan\SampleModule\Setup\Patch\Schema;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface;

/**
* Patch is mechanism, that allows to do atomic upgrade data changes
*/
class PatchName implements SchemaPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    )
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    /**
     * Do Upgrade
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->addColumn(
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('cms_page'),
            'custom',
            [
               'type' => Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
               'nullable' => false,
               'comment'  => 'custom',
            ]
        );
        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [

        ];
    }
}
```

After that we need to add field in `ui_component`

> app/code/Pawan/SampleModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="general">
        <field name="custom" sortOrder="10" formElement="checkbox">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Custom toggle</label>
                <dataScope>custom</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**Run following commands**

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento cache:flush

**Note**

- Vendor name - Pawan
- Module name - SampleModule
- Custom filed name : custom

You need to update above names as per your module/field name

Hope above will help!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. will try and let you know.

Comment: welcome @SaravananDS ..) please let me know if have any issue..

Comment: Sure, thank you...

Comment: Its helped me to create the toggle element... Thank you....

Comment: glad to know it worked :)